# How to check if a file exists in Go?

Tags: file, go, standard-library

Go's standard library does not have a function solely intended to check if a file exists or not (like Python's [`os.path.exists`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists)). What is the **idiomatic** way to do it?

Comment: I don't really get it. At the same minute you say there is no standard function and you write an answer with the standard function. What am I missing ? Shouldn't at least the question be fixed ?

Comment: One should better avoid inquiring file existence. B/c of the racy nature of the answer, the obtained information says actually nothing useful above the file existed in the time asked - but it may not exist anymore. The recommendable way is to simply open a file and check if that fails or not.

Comment: @zzzz (I know it's been years, this comment is for new readers) I agree in the general case. But my app loads a third party library that takes some file path as initialization data but segfaults if the file does not exist. I think this is a valid scenario for checking if the file exists withou trying to open it to be able to report the error without a fatal crash, as my code doesn't need to read file contents or write to the file directly.

Answer (score 1062, accepted):

To check if a file doesn't exist, equivalent to Python's `if not os.path.exists(filename)`:

```
if _, err := os.Stat("/path/to/whatever"); errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist) {
  // path/to/whatever does not exist
}
```

To check if a file exists, equivalent to Python's `if os.path.exists(filename)`:

```
if _, err := os.Stat("/path/to/whatever"); err == nil {
  // path/to/whatever exists

} else if errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist) {
  // path/to/whatever does *not* exist

} else {
  // Schrodinger: file may or may not exist. See err for details.

  // Therefore, do *NOT* use !os.IsNotExist(err) to test for file existence


}
```

Comment: sometimes it return ENOTDIR instead of `NOTEXIST`, for example, if `/etc/bashrc` exist, the `/etc/bashrc/foobar` will return `ENOTDIR`

Comment: The second snippet is more subtly wrong; the condition should be `!os.IsNotExist(err)`. It's possible the file exists but `os.Stat` fails for other reasons (eg. permission, failing disk). Using `err == nil` as the condition incorrectly categorises such failures as "the file does not exist".

Comment: To check if a file exists is wrong: err is nil if file exists

Comment: Make sure to expand ~ or else it will return false... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609732/expand-tilde-to-home-directory/43578461#43578461

Comment: You could use os.IsExist() depending the case, could be more idiomatically instead of making a double negation when doing !os.IsNotExistant()

Comment: The latest docs tell you to use `errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist)` in any new code: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/os/error.go#L90-L91

Comment: @PalKerecsenyi Thanks for mentioning that! I think it's noteworthy enough that it's worth being its own answer to this question, so I [posted a new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66405130/2338327) that mentions `errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist`).

Comment: @PalKerecsenyi the comment linked suggests `fs.ErrNotExist` because `os.ErrNotExist` is specific to the`os` package. The correct check is `errors.Is(err, fs.ErrNotExist)`.

Comment: If you want to check if a lot of files exist, you can replace `_,. err := os.Stat(path)` with: `var fs syscall.Stat_t; err := syscall.Stat(path, &fs)`, and you'll save yourself two allocs.

Comment: Running on an old, spinning harddrive, `os.Stat` seems to take way longer if the file exists than when it doesn't, which makes me think that `os.Stat` actually loads information from where the file is stored in case the file exists, but knows it doesn't have to do that if it doesn't. Is there a way to check _only_ weather a file exists?

Comment: is it possible to restrict the results to text files? Or at least exclude results like "./." which results as valid input for target filenames while it should be discarded by the input validation

Answer (score 160):

Answer by **Caleb Spare** posted in [gonuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/Ayx-BMNdMFo/4rL8FFHr8v4J) mailing list.

> [...] It's not actually needed very often and [...] using `os.Stat` is 
>   easy enough for the cases where it is required.
>
> [...] For instance: if you are going to open the file, there's no reason to check whether it exists first. The file could disappear in between checking and opening, and anyway you'll need to check the `os.Open` error regardless. So you simply call `os.IsNotExist(err)` after you try 
>   to open the file, and deal with its non-existence there (if that requires special handling).
>
> [...] You don't need to check for the paths existing at all (and you shouldn't).
>
> - `os.MkdirAll` works whether or not the paths already exist. (Also you need to check the error from that call.)
> - Instead of using `os.Create`, you should use `os.OpenFile(path, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_EXCL, 0666)` . That way you'll get an error if the file already exists. Also this doesn't have a race condition with something else making the file, unlike your version which checks for existence beforehand.

Taken from: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/Ayx-BMNdMFo/4rL8FFHr8v4J

Comment: Thank you for quoting this because I had a lot of trouble finding how to create a file only if the file does not exist (`os.O_EXCL`) because I can never remember what these flags mean. I thought `os.O_CREATE` already implied that the file must be created and not exist beforehand.

Answer (score 72):

The first thing to consider is that it is rare that you would only want to check whether or not a file exists. In most situations, you're trying to do something with the file if it exists. In Go, any time you try to perform some operation on a file that doesn't exist, the result should be a specific error (`os.ErrNotExist`) and the best thing to do is check whether the return `err` value (e.g. when calling a function like `os.OpenFile(...)`) is `os.ErrNotExist`.

The recommended way to do this **used to be**:

```golang
file, err := os.OpenFile(...)
if os.IsNotExist(err) {
    // handle the case where the file doesn't exist
}
```

However, **since the addition of `errors.Is` in Go 1.13** (released in late 2019), [the new recommendation is to use `errors.Is`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/5ff7ec98b7727b3641df25200345b1aa50b6ff35/src/os/error.go#L90-L91):

```golang
file, err := os.OpenFile(...)
if errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist) {
    // handle the case where the file doesn't exist
}
```

---

**It's usually best to avoid using `os.Stat` to check for the existence of a file before you attempt to do something with it, because it will always be possible for the file to be renamed, deleted, etc. in the window of time before you do something with it.**

However, if you're OK with this caveat and you really, truly just want to check whether a file exists without then proceeding to do something useful with it (as a contrived example, let's say that you're writing a pointless CLI tool that tells you whether or not a file exists and then exits `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`), then the recommended way to do it would be:

```
if _, err := os.Stat(filename); errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist) {
    // file does not exist
} else {
    // file exists
}
```

Comment: I have a question how do u know if is a file or a directory using this method?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the (not recommended!) `os.Stat` approach: `os.Stat` returns `info, err` and if `err` is nil, `info` is a FileInfo object that you can use to determine whether the thing that exists is a file or a directory. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791506/2338327) for more details.

Comment: No I was asking about the recommended method `file, err := os.OpenFile(...) if errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist) {` this is nice when you already have the file but sometimes you get a dir or a file if a file you do something if no, and is a dir then you do some other. There are 100000 of examples using the `os.Stat` and you mentioned that we should avoid the uses of that that is why I asked. How to use the recommended method and check if is dir or handle this scenario.

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure, off hand, what would happen if you called OpenFile on a directory. If it returns an error, then I think in most cases it would be sufficient to handle the error the same way you would handle any other error.

Comment: shark attacks are rare, except at the beach.
the need to specifically check if a file exists is rare, except under the question titled “How to check if a file exists in Go”.
in my case, if the file exists, my work is done; if it doesn't exist, i must generate it.

Comment: That's a good counterexample!

Comment: ...although you could use `os.OpenFile(path, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_EXCL, 0666)` to create the file only if it doesn't already exist, as mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 55):

You should use the `os.Stat()` and `os.IsNotExist()` functions as in the following example:

```
func Exists(name string) (bool, error) {
    _, err := os.Stat(name)
    if err == nil {
        return true, nil
    }
    if errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist) {
        return false, nil
    }
    return false, err
}
```

edit1: fixed issue of returning true when under some circumstances.
edit2: switched to using errors.Is() from os.IsNotExist(), which many say is a [best-practice](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38198) and [here](https://stefanxo.com/go-anti-patterns-os-isexisterr-os-isnotexisterr/)

Comment: Beware: as http://stackoverflow.com/a/22467409/712014 pointed out, this code returns true, even if the file does not exist, for example when Stat() returns permission denied.

Answer (score 30):

What other answers missed, is that the path given to the function could actually be a directory. Following function makes sure, that the path is really a file.

```
func fileExists(filename string) bool {
    info, err := os.Stat(filename)
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        return false
    }
    return !info.IsDir()
}
```

Another thing to point out: This code could still lead to a race condition, where another thread or process deletes or creates the specified file, while the fileExists function is running.

If you're worried about this, use a lock in your threads, serialize the access to this function or use an inter-process semaphore if multiple applications are involved. If other applications are involved, outside of your control, you're out of luck, I guess.

Comment: If other applications are involved, you might want to keep your files in a separate folder. If you are creating new files, O_EXCL is your friend to avoid races (if the platform you are using supports that flag).

Comment: Do not use this cause `info` could be nil when calling `return !info.IsDir()`

Answer (score 23):

The [example by user11617](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12527546/4907533) is incorrect; it will report that the file exists even in cases where it does not, but there was an error of some other sort.

The signature should be Exists(string) (bool, error). And then, as it happens, the call sites are no better.

The code he wrote would better as:

```
func Exists(name string) bool {
    _, err := os.Stat(name)
    return !os.IsNotExist(err)
}
```

But I suggest this instead:

```
func Exists(name string) (bool, error) {
  _, err := os.Stat(name)
  if os.IsNotExist(err) {
    return false, nil
  }
  return err != nil, err
}
```

Comment: Your second example needs to destructure multiple return values - e.g. _, err := os.Stat(name)

Comment: Why return `err != nil` instead of `err == nil` ? If there's an error, then the file probably doesn't exist?

Answer (score 13):

```
    _, err := os.Stat(file)
    if err == nil {
        log.Printf("file %s exists", file)
    } else if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        log.Printf("file %s not exists", file)
    } else {
        log.Printf("file %s stat error: %v", file, err)
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Best way to check if file exists:

```
if _, err := os.Stat("/path/to/file"); err == nil || os.IsExist(err) {
    // your code here if file exists
}
```

Answer (score 9):

basicly

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func fileExists(path string) bool {
    _, err := os.Stat(path)
    return !os.IsNotExist(err)
}

func main() {

    var file string = "foo.txt"
    exist := fileExists(file)
    
    if exist {
        fmt.Println("file exist")
    } else {

        fmt.Println("file not exists")
    }

}
```

[run example](https://play.golang.org/p/8vbIzc2P8Fj)

other way

with os.Open

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func fileExists(path string) bool {
    _, err := os.Open(path) // For read access.
    return err == nil

}

func main() {

    fmt.Println(fileExists("d4d.txt"))

}
```

[run it](https://play.golang.org/p/_WfVKlGFcRs)

Answer (score 8):

The function example:

```
func file_is_exists(f string) bool {
    _, err := os.Stat(f)
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        return false
    }
    return err == nil
}
```

Comment: Isn't the if redundant?

Comment: it's not, but the logic is broken currently.
The function should only return false if the file does not exist, however currently it returns false on any error. Possibly it should panic instead.
Also, "file is exists" is broken English.

Answer (score 8):

Let's look at few aspects first, both the function provided by `os` package of `golang` are not utilities but error checkers, what do I mean by that is they are just a wrapper to handle errors on cross platform.

So basically if `os.Stat` if this function doesn't give any error that means the file is existing if it does you need to check what kind of error it is, here comes the use of these two function `os.IsNotExist` and `os.IsExist`.

This can be understood as the `Stat` of the file throwing error because it doesn't exists or is it throwing error because it exist and there is some problem with it.

The parameter that these functions take is of type `error`, although you might be able to pass `nil` to it but it wouldn't make sense.

This also points to the fact that `IsExist is not same as !IsNotExist`, they are way two different things.

So now if you want to know if a given file exist in go, I would prefer the best way is:

```
if _, err := os.Stat(path/to/file); !os.IsNotExist(err){
   //TODO
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in other answers, it is possible to construct the required behaviour / errors from using different flags with `os.OpenFile`. In fact, `os.Create` is just a sensible-defaults shorthand for doing so:

```golang
// Create creates or truncates the named file. If the file already exists,
// it is truncated. If the file does not exist, it is created with mode 0666
// (before umask). If successful, methods on the returned File can
// be used for I/O; the associated file descriptor has mode O_RDWR.
// If there is an error, it will be of type *PathError.
func Create(name string) (*File, error) {
    return OpenFile(name, O_RDWR|O_CREATE|O_TRUNC, 0666)
}
```

You should combine these flags yourself to get the behaviour you are interested in:

```golang
// Flags to OpenFile wrapping those of the underlying system. Not all
// flags may be implemented on a given system.
const (
    // Exactly one of O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR must be specified.
    O_RDONLY int = syscall.O_RDONLY // open the file read-only.
    O_WRONLY int = syscall.O_WRONLY // open the file write-only.
    O_RDWR   int = syscall.O_RDWR   // open the file read-write.
    // The remaining values may be or'ed in to control behavior.
    O_APPEND int = syscall.O_APPEND // append data to the file when writing.
    O_CREATE int = syscall.O_CREAT  // create a new file if none exists.
    O_EXCL   int = syscall.O_EXCL   // used with O_CREATE, file must not exist.
    O_SYNC   int = syscall.O_SYNC   // open for synchronous I/O.
    O_TRUNC  int = syscall.O_TRUNC  // truncate regular writable file when opened.
)
```

Depending on what you pick, you will get different errors.

Below is an example which will either truncate an existing file, or fail when a file exists.

```
openOpts := os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE
if truncateWhenExists {
    openOpts |= os.O_TRUNC // file will be truncated
} else {
    openOpts |= os.O_EXCL  // file must not exist
}
f, err := os.OpenFile(filePath, openOpts, 0644)
// ... do stuff
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is my take on a file exists method. It also checks that the file is not a directory and in case of an error, returns it as well.

```golang
// FileExists checks if a file exists (and it is not a directory).
func FileExists(filePath string) (bool, error) {
    info, err := os.Stat(filePath)
    if err == nil {
        return !info.IsDir(), nil
    }
    if errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist) {
        return false, nil
    }
    return false, err
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is how I check if a file exists in `Go 1.16`

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/fs"
    "os"
)

func main () {
    if _, err:= os.Stat("/path/to/file"); errors.Is(err, fs.ErrNotExist){
        fmt.Print(err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Print("file exists")
    }
}
```