# Expand tilde to home directory

Tags: path, go

I have a program that accepts a destination folder where files will be created. My program should be able to handle absolute paths as well as relative paths. My problem is that I don't know how to expand `~` to the home directory.

My function to expand the destination looks like this. If the path given is absolute it does nothing otherwise it joins the relative path with the current working directory.

```
import "path"
import "os"

// var destination *String is the user input

func expandPath() {
        if path.IsAbs(*destination) {
                return
        }
        cwd, err := os.Getwd()
        checkError(err)
        *destination = path.Join(cwd, *destination)
}
```

Since [`path.Join`](http://godoc.org/path#Join) doesn't expand `~` it doesn't work if the user passes something like `~/Downloads` as the destination.

How should I solve this in a cross platform way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally, the `~` is expanded by the shell *before* your program sees it.
Adjust how your program acquires its arguments from the command line in a way compatible with the shell expansion mechanism.

One of the possible problems is using [exec.Command](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) like this:

```
cmd := exec.Command("some-binary", someArg) // say 'someArg' is "~/foo"
```

which will not get expanded. You can, for example use instead:

```
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", fmt.Sprintf("'some-binary %q'", someArg))
```

which will get the standard `~` expansion from the shell.

EDIT: fixed the 'sh -c' example.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the shell does that.

Comment: @jnml, I'd say the first single quote in the format string is misplaced and should instead be right before the `%q` placeholder to read `fmt.Sprintf("some-binary '%q'", someArg)`

Comment: @kostix: I don't think so. The value returned from Sprintf in the above example should be `'some-binary "/home/login/foo"'`. Didn't tested it, maybe the outer single quotes should be actually removed. They are correct on the command line, though.

Comment: @jnml, yes, you're correct: the `%q` itself produces a single-quoted string (I missed that). But I think my initial idea still holds: whatever string the call to `fmt.Sprintf` produces will be a single argument, so there's no need to further quote it.

Comment: This may be true if you get the path as CLI argument, but not if you get a path string from anywhere else.

Answer (score 110):

Go provides the package [os/user](http://golang.org/pkg/os/user/), which allows you to get the current user, and for any user, their home directory:

```
usr, _ := user.Current()
dir := usr.HomeDir
```

Then, use [path/filepath](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/) to combine both strings to a valid path:

```
if path == "~" {
    // In case of "~", which won't be caught by the "else if"
    path = dir
} else if strings.HasPrefix(path, "~/") {
    // Use strings.HasPrefix so we don't match paths like
    // "/something/~/something/"
    path = filepath.Join(dir, path[2:])
}
```

(Note that user.Current() is not implemented in the go playground (likely for security reasons), so I can't give an easily runnable example).

Comment: Fails for valid paths like `~/a~z`.

Comment: Really? The last parameter defines how many instances to replace; it should stop after the first one.

Comment: Note also that the shell supports `~user/foo` which refers to `foo` in `user`'s home directory too.

Comment: What about `somedir/~/someotherdir`?

Comment: The code should read `dir+"/"`, otherwise the result is missing one `/`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it shouldn't matter. Any utility which uses filepaths (ie, `os.Open`, unix commands, etc) should treat `/path/to/dir` and `/path/to/dir/` the same way.

Comment: Rather than `strings.Replace` you can use `filepath.Join(usr.HomeDir, path[2:])` to make sure the directory separator is properly added. On Windows at least the HomeDir is not terminated by a slash.

Comment: This answer is 99% right. But `if strings.HasPrefix(path, "~/")` is more accurate than `if path[:2] == "~/"`. The latter will fail if the path is zero or one characters long. Also the path "~" is not handled correctly -- it should also expand to $HOME.

Comment: Yep, `if path == "~" { return usr.HomeDir }` should be before the `HasPrefix`  check. [Play](https://play.golang.org/p/bblnSrH9aP1)

Comment: Good catch; fixed.

Comment: The behavior of this is different than what for example [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) and [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) do to expand `~`: Usually, `~` is expanded to `$HOME` if it's set, and as a fallback it's set to the user's home directory (as defined in `/etc/passwd`). But the `os/user`package [only checks the user's home directory](https://golang.org/src/os/user/lookup_unix.go) and ignores `$HOME`.

Answer (score 25):

In general the `~` is expanded by your shell *before* it gets to your program. But there are [some limitations](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html).

In general is [ill-advised to do it manually in Go](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4140).

I had the same problem in a program of mine and what I have understood is that if I use the flag format as `--flag=~/myfile`, it is not expanded. But if you run `--flag ~/myfile` it is expanded by the shell (the `=` is missing and the filename appears as a separate "word").

Comment: This is both simpler, and more correct than either the accepted answer, or the most upvoted answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you are expanding tilde '~' for use with `exec.Command()` you should use the users local shell for expansion.

```
// 'sh', 'bash' and 'zsh' all respect the '-c' argument
cmd := exec.Command(os.Getenv("SHELL"), "-c", "cat ~/.myrc")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
}
```

However; when loading application config files such as `~./myrc` this solution is not acceptable. The following has worked well for me across multiple platforms

```
import "os/user"
import "path/filepath"

func expand(path string) (string, error) {
    if len(path) == 0 || path[0] != '~' {
        return path, nil
    }

    usr, err := user.Current()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return filepath.Join(usr.HomeDir, path[1:]), nil
}
```

**NOTE:** `usr.HomeDir` does not respect `$HOME` instead determines the home directory by reading the `/etc/passwd` file via the `getpwuid_r` syscall on (osx/linux). On windows it uses the `OpenCurrentProcessToken` syscall to determine the users home directory.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for providing a full example (with error checking and all!) But you also need to `import "path/filepath"` or your code won't work.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question but there is another option now. You can use [go-homedir](https://github.com/mitchellh/go-homedir) to expand the tidle to the user's homedir:

```
myPath := "~/.ssh"
fmt.Printf("path: %s; with expansion: %s", myPath, homedir.Expand(myPath))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on go >= 1.12:

```golang
if strings.HasPrefix(path, "~/") {
    home, _ := os.UserHomeDir()
    path = filepath.Join(home, path[2:])    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try this (obviously it needs to be fixed to handle errors properly):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Expand("~/.config/"))
}

func Expand(s string) string {
    home, _ := os.UserHomeDir()
    return strings.Replace(s, "~", home, 1)
}
```