# Different result between run bash command directly and through exec.Command

Tags: go, command, exec

On Linux OS, run "realpath ~/bin" gives the correct path "/home/user1/bin".

But when I run it as bellow:

```
cmd := exec.Command("realpath", "~/bin")
var out bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println("Realapth:", out.String())
```

I got `panic: exit status 1`.

BTW: with command as below:

```
cmd := exec.Command("realpath", "--help")
```

I can get correct help message for `realpath` command. I think that means it is really in my executable path.

Comment: `Go` will not expand `~` to user's home directory in this case. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17617721/3781709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the command in a shell (e.g. bash), a [tilde-prefix](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) is expanded by the shell before being passed to `realpath`.

However if you run it in a go application, tilde is left as is and `realpath` assumes it as a part of the path name. To see the difference, you can try the following command in shell (Linux OS):

```
//1. correctly expanded
realpath './bin'

//2. tilde not expanded
realpath '~/bin'

//3. tilde expansion
realpath ~/bin
```

The (2) should failed, and the situation in your go application is similar to this. To verify, change your go code as follows:

```
cmd := exec.Command("realpath", "~/bin")
var out bytes.Buffer
var serr bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
cmd.Stderr = &serr
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error = %v, %v\n", err, serr.String())
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println("Realapth:", out.String())
```

You should be able to observe error message produced by `realpath` command.