# os.Stat: permission denied => error(syscall.Errno) EACCES (13)

Tags: go

I'm creating a directory inside a **unit test** like this:

```golang
// The directory which is going to be created next to unit test executable.
const DirName string = "test-files"
```

Creating directory:

```golang
    // Create the directory if doesn't already exist.
    err := os.MkdirAll(DirName, os.ModeDir)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Compose a sample file path to double-check its existence.
    pth := DirName + string(os.PathSeparator) + "samplefile.txt"


    exists, err := doesExist(pth)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

And checking file existence:

```golang
// Does file exist?
func doesExist(pth string) (bool, error) {

    // Check file existence
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/10510718/3405291
    if _, err := os.Stat(pth); err != nil {
        if os.IsNotExist(err) {
            return false, nil
        } else {
            return true, err
        }
    }

    // Above conditions are skipped,
    // therefore file exists.
    return true, nil
}
```

The above code returns this error:

> os.Stat: permission denied

> error(syscall.Errno) EACCES (13)

I can double-check that the directory is actually created. But the permissions are `d---------`:

```sh
> ls -lh
d--------- 2 m3 users    6 Dec 23 20:30 test-files
```

How can I create the directory with the appropriate permissions?

Comment: You could use os.Mkdir where you also can set the permissions.

Comment: `MkDir` is already creating a directory, you don't need to set the directory mode bit. You do however need to set the correct permissions to access the directory.

Comment: Take a look at this https://golangbyexample.com/create-directory-folder-golang/

Comment: @Spoofed Does `os.MkdirAll` have permission parameter?

Comment: Are you aware of [`umask`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask)? It might be intervening here. While we're at it, please consider using `path/filepath.Join` instead of messing with the string concatenation using `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're abusing the `os.ModeDir` constant. It's invented to serve as the bit mask to check whether the file's [mode+permissions bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions) (returned by, say, `os.(*File).Stat` indicate it's a directory.

The default permission mode bits to create a directory are `0777` but they are subject to [`umask`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask).

Comment: Right, the error got resolved by `syscall.Umask(0)  err := os.MkdirAll(DirName, 0775)` as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61645606/3405291

Comment: @user3405291: you generally *should not* **set** the umask, and *should* obey the existing umask while providing wide-open permissions. See [my answer to that same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59963154/1256452).

Comment: @torek Thanks, I'm going study it :)